# Jekyll Serve error. Browser does not display page

Tags: jekyll, webrick

After following installation steps for Jekyll I ran

```
jekyll serve --verbose
```

I then go to the browser type: 127.0.0.1:4000 (which gives me a The 127.0.0.1 page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

I get the following response from the server log:

```
2016-09-12 00:59:27] INFO WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-09-12 00:59:27] INFO ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-darwin14]
[2016-09-12 00:59:27] DEBUG WEBrick::HTTPServlet::FileHandler is mounted on /.
[2016-09-12 00:59:27] DEBUG unmount .
[2016-09-12 00:59:27] DEBUG Jekyll::Commands::Serve::Servlet is mounted on .
Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
[2016-09-12 00:59:27] INFO WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=64929 port=4000
Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
[2016-09-12 01:00:18] DEBUG accept: 127.0.0.1:56926
[2016-09-12 01:00:18] DEBUG accept: 127.0.0.1:56927
[2016-09-12 01:00:19] DEBUG Jekyll::Commands::Serve::Servlet is invoked.
[2016-09-12 01:00:40] DEBUG close: 127.0.0.1:56927
[2016-09-12 01:00:49] DEBUG close: 127.0.0.1:56926
[2016-09-12 01:00:51] DEBUG accept: 127.0.0.1:56984
[2016-09-12 01:00:51] DEBUG Jekyll::Commands::Serve::Servlet is invoked.
[2016-09-12 01:01:21] DEBUG close: 127.0.0.1:56984
[2016-09-12 01:09:44] DEBUG accept: 127.0.0.1:57192
[2016-09-12 01:09:44] DEBUG Jekyll::Commands::Serve::Servlet is invoked.
```

Any opinions, ideas ?

Comment: Silly question first. Have you built a site for webrick to serve?